# How can I set the language in text with python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I create word files using the python-docx library. I want to be able to set different parts of the document to different languages. How can the language be set with python-docx? Preferrably, I would like to do it at the run-level, since I need different languages on the same line (it's a dual language document I am creating). However, there does not seem to by any language attribute for runs, nor for paragraphs.

Comment: There is a core property in document level: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/coreprops.html?highlight=lang

Comment: I don't get this to work. As I understand, the core properties are document wide, and a property called "Language" does exists (under Properties/Custom), but setting it using e.g. '
core_properties.language = "Spanish"' does not change it in the document, secondly, it is probably not the right language property. There is another language property, which is available under Tools/Language. This second language property can be different in different parts of the text and is the one which determines spelling. This is the one I am after.

Comment: On python-docx version 0.8.10 there is a property called [language](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/coreprops.html?highlight=lang#properties) Yet no information on how to use it.

Answer (score 15):

I think the language has to be set via document styles in `word/styles.xml`
or on run level.
But currently there is no API support for this task in python-docx.

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45646970),
you can try the following code to alter the properties in the oxml element objects.
`p4` shows the run level attempt.
(Tested with [python-docx==0.8.10](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/) + LibreOffice Writer with German and English language dictionaries.)

*Note: The language field in the [Core Document Properties](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/coreprops.html?highlight=language#properties) is just a meta data information
and is not used for global spell checking.*

```py
import docx # python-docx==0.8.10


doc = docx.Document()

# For new document (document-wide):
# Set language value in the documents' default Run's Properties element.
styles_element = doc.styles.element
rpr_default = styles_element.xpath('./w:docDefaults/w:rPrDefault/w:rPr')[0]
lang_default = rpr_default.xpath('w:lang')[0]
lang_default.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:val'),'de-DE')

title = doc.add_paragraph('Rechtschreibprüfung', style='Title')

p1 = doc.add_paragraph(
    'Das ist ein deutscher Satz. '
    'Die Rechtschreibprüfung sollte nichts anstreichen.',
    style='Normal'
    )

# For existing styles:
# For styles without a language value
# you can append one explicitly by
# iterating over those styles in the document.
for my_style in doc.styles:
    style = doc.styles[my_style.name]
    rpr = style.element.get_or_add_rPr()
    lang = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:lang')
    if not rpr.xpath('w:lang'):
        lang.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:val'),'de-DE')
        lang.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:eastAsia'),'en-US')
        lang.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:bidi'),'ar-SA')
        rpr.append(lang)

p2 = doc.add_paragraph(
    'This sentence is written in English. '
    'The automatic spell checking should complain, '
    'because all styles’ language was set to German.',
    style='Quote'
    )

# For addressing specifc styles:
# Update (or append to) a specific style,
# e.g. in order to use multiple styles
# to handle more than one language per document.
body_style = doc.styles['Body Text']
body_rpr = body_style.element.get_or_add_rPr()
body_lang = body_rpr.xpath('w:lang')[0]
body_lang.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:val'),'en-US')

p3 = doc.add_paragraph(
    'This sentence is written again in English. '
    'The automatic spell checking should not complain, '
    'because this style’s language now has been set to English.',
    style='Body Text'
    )

# Run Level:
# For mixing multiple languages
# within the same style per paragraph.
p4 = doc.add_paragraph(style='Body Text')
p4_text = p4.add_run()
p4_text.add_text(
    'On Run Level: This sentence is written once again in English. '
    'Spell check = OK | '
    )
# Add a new run with its language
# differing from the style's language value.
p4_text = p4.add_run()
p4_rpr = p4_text.element.get_or_add_rPr()
p4_run_lang = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:lang')
p4_run_lang.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:val'),'de-DE')
p4_run_lang.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:eastAsia'),'en-US')
p4_run_lang.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:bidi'),'ar-SA')
p4_rpr.append(p4_run_lang)
p4_text.add_text(
    'Und das ist noch einmal ein deutscher Satz. '
    'Rechtschreibprüfung = okay'
    )

doc.save('my-document.docx')
```

Comment: This answer solves both the document wide language setting and also a per run setting. Excellent!

Comment: I opened an issue on Github back in 2019: [Setting the document language has no effect](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/727). No response so far. This answer from winkelband solves the problem. +1 from my side!