# How to get python-docx working with complex scripts?

Tags: python, openxml, right-to-left, python-docx, bidi

I have a working docx generator which works fine for European languages, and I'm trying to add complex script support. I found another question with some recipes to try: [python-docx add_style with CTL (Complex text layout) language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627652/python-docx-add-style-with-ctl-complex-text-layout-language)

I managed to get it working so that complex-script text comes out in the correct typeface and size, but I can't get bidirectional (right-to-left) text working. The obvious "x.font.rtl = True" doesn't work, and neither does the spell given in the other post ("lang.set(qn('w:bidi'),'fa-IR')"). I had to take out the line " "rpr.get_or_add_sz()" from his recipe, which left me with an unreadable file, but everything else works without it and I don't think that it's related to this problem.

Here is the style as it appears in the generated document's styles.xml file:

```
<w:style w:styleId="Hebrew" w:type="paragraph" w:customStyle="1">
    <w:name w:val="Hebrew"/>
    <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:jc w:val="right"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:rtl/>
        <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
        <w:lang w:bidi="he-IL"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

Can anyone advise me on what to do to get paragraphs in right-to-left languages working?

Comment: I haven't done anything with python-docx shortly after that post (almost 2 years) so I don't remember much about it (it might have changed the way it does some things since then even). But comparing my xml in "Xml explanation" part with yours, I can see that you don't have a "w:val" before "w:bidi". Maybe you should add that via code too. I think my base.docx file had that so I didn't need to add it via code. Also *maybe* you need ascii and hAnsi too in your rFonts. Like my example. Also please add python-docx tag to your question so relevant people could find this post.

Comment: Thanks, but what should the "w.val" look like? What would I need to do to insert it? I don't see anything in your example to guide me.

Comment: It is in my example (read it again). Mine was this: w:val="en-Us". Add it like I did w:bidi. `lang.set(qn('w:val'),'en-Us')`

Comment: Ah, OK, found it. I've now got <w:rFonts w:hAnsi="Arial" w:ascii="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
<w:rtl/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
<w:lang w:val="en-UK" w:bidi="he-IL"/>
but none of the changes made any difference -- the para still shows up as LTR.

Comment: does `rpr.get_or_add_sz()` still make an unreadable file?

Comment: my base.docx "normal" paragraph style:  `<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Normal">
        <w:name w:val="Normal" /> <w:qFormat /> <w:pPr> <w:widowControl /> <w:bidi w:val="1" /> <w:jc w:val="both" /> </w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="FreeMono" w:hAnsi="FreeMono" w:eastAsia="WenQuanYi Micro Hei" w:cs="Nazli" />
            <w:color w:val="00000A" />
            <w:sz w:val="28" />
            <w:szCs w:val="28" />
            <w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="zh-CN" w:bidi="fa-IR" />
        </w:rPr>
    </w:style>`

Comment: Throw it into an online XML beautifier so you could read it better. I can at least see 1 thing different and that is: "<w:bidi w:val="1" />" inside <w:pPr> tag.

Comment: When it didn't work, I started with "document = Document(); document.add_paragraph(); document.save()" and added one line at a time before the add_paragraph(), trying to open the result each time. I got as far as "rpr.get_or_add_sz()" before it broke.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190385/discussion-between-roar-and-user1636349).

Comment: First let me say that adding the w:bidi to w:pPr did the trick! Thank you! (I have another issue, though...)

Comment: Did you see my last post in the chat?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Everything now works properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments above, and with much help from ROAR (thanks, ROAR!) I got everything working.

ROAR's recipe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627652/python-docx-add-style-with-ctl-complex-text-layout-language) worked perfectly except that calling rpr.get_or_add_sz() gave me an unreadable .docx file. Leaving it out made everything work and didn't appear to cause any problems. The crucial missing link was to add the following to <w:pPr> in the style:

```
<w:bidi w:val="1">
<w:jc w:val="both"/>
```

There is a my_style.get_or_add_pPr() method to get a reference to the <w:pPr> section of the style, and the code is then similar to the code for updating <w:rPr>:

```
w_nsmap = '{'+ppr.nsmap['w']+'}'
bidi = None
jc = None
for element in ppr:
  if element.tag == w_nsmap + 'bidi':
    bidi = element
  if element.tag == w_nsmap + 'jc':
    jc = element
if bidi is None:
  bidi = OxmlElement('w:bidi')
if jc is None:
  jc = OxmlElement('w:jc')
bidi.set(qn('w:val'),'1')
jc.set(qn('w:val'),'both')
ppr.append(bidi)
ppr.append(jc)
```

The final thing I needed was to deal with mixed-language text, which I did by breaking the text into multiple runs. The paras of Hebrew text I was dealing with were given the modified style with rtl=True, but I split out any ASCII sequences which started and ended with a letter:

```
[A-Za-z][\u0020-\u007e]*[A-Aa-z]
```

into separate runs with rtl=False.