# Can't use RTL direction when using font.name or font.size in python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I'm using python-docx for writing new ms words.
Python 3.8 - Win10 x32
There is code:

```
doc = docx.Document()
style = doc.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'B Mitra'
font.size = docx.shared.Pt(13)
font.rtl = True
doc.add_paragraph("Hi in Persian= سلام")
doc.save("tst.docx")
```

without `font.rtl=True` both `font.size` and `font.name` will set on paragraph but when i use `font.rtl=True` the size and font won't set. just direction will set.
Any ideas?
 Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A style can have more than one font, like one for latin characters and another for cursive script (used for languages like Arabic and Persian). `style.font` is only settings for the latin font because that's the most common. There is no built-in `python-pptx` support for setting the cursive font, although if you search around you may find someone who has managed to get it done.

This other question has some information:
[python-docx add_style with CTL (Complex text layout) language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627652/python-docx-add-style-with-ctl-complex-text-layout-language)

I found it by searching on `python-docx arabic font`.

Also you can look into creating a "starting" or "template" .docx file that you load using

```
document = docx.Document("my-template-document.docx")
```

Then you can use Word to make all the paragraph styles and other document settings you want and just have `python-docx` use those styles where you want them.

Comment: How is that a solution?